# get an email once the mysql dump is success

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, cron

i am trying to backup one of my mysql database in a ubuntu server.
i want to get an email once the backup is success if not an error via email.
this is my simple script

*mysqldump -u db_user -p******* database > /var/backups/database-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
  #!/bin/bash
  mysqldump -v -u db_user -p******* database > /var/backups/database-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql 2> error.log

 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
  mail -s "Mysql Dump failed" you@youremailid.com < error.log
  else

  echo "Mysql dumped successful " | mail -s "Mysql Dump Done" you@youremail.com
  fi
```

I didn't test,check your own environment

Comment: thanks its working, can you help me to setup the from address?